# Certain HTML hidden on IE10/11 on Win7 Only, Works on all other IE versions

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-10

I am hoping someone has run into this before. I am having an issue on a Windows 7 / IE10 and IE11 configuration.

For this page here: http://info.triagestaff.com/traveling-nurse-jobs/ I have a form and, below the submit button, there is some eligibility requirements. Pretty simple stuff, no CSS3 or anything.

The problem is, this text does not show up on Windows 7 using IE10 or IE11. It does work on Windows 7 using IE9 and even IE8. It does work on all newer versions of Windows (8, 8.1, 10, etc).

I'm really at a loss for what would be different with those specific configurations. I've tried changing margins, padding, positioning, etc. It's like the bottom just falls behind the footer, which also isn't fully appearing in those two specific instances.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. This is obviously a very specific use-case, but I'll post it here in case anyone else is running into it.

I am using the Bones WordPress framework and they have the following CSS apply to all p tags.

```
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
   -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
      -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
       -o-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
          font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
```

In IE10 and IE11 on Win7, this causes all p tag wrapped elements to simply disappear.

I noticed that all my p tags were missing, so I tried wrapping them in a span and they reappeared. From there I looked for the rules applying to p tags and found the font-feature-settings. Once I removed those, everything appeared as it should.

Now that I know what I'm looking for, I found similar posts here on stackoverflow, but I'm leaving this in case someone googles the same issue.